# Pyqt5 MySQL database connection not opening through worker thread using Python3

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, pyqt, pyqt5

I am having problems connecting to my mysql database from my pyqt worker thread.

I can connect to the DB manually through command line, but my pyqt5 worker thread seems to be unable to open the DB.  I have the QMYSQL drivers available, and I have temporarily set full privileges for all users logging in to rule out that scenario, and I have made the username and password login as default, but still I cannot connect.

Just to outline, the MySQL db resides on a Ubuntu system and I am connecting from a Windows 10 PC.

Here's my code so far and the outputs.

```
class Worker(QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        print('Opening DB')
        self.db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase().addDatabase("QMYSQL")
        print('Driver available? ', self.db.isDriverAvailable("QMYSQL"))
        self.db.setHostName(192.168.56.1)
        self.db.setDatabaseName('Automation_DB')
        self.db.setUserName('root')
        self.db.setPassword('root')
        self.db.open()
        self.query = QSqlQuery(self.db)
        self.qstring = None
        print('isopened? ',self.db.isOpen())
        print('open? ',self.db.open())
        print('Last Error ', self.db.lastError().text())
        print('Drivers ', self.db.drivers())

        try:
            self.db.open()
            print('Check open? ', self.db.open())

        except Exception as e:
            if not self.db.open():
                print('DB open error', e)
            else:
                print('Error')
```

Command line output Below:

```
Opening DB
Driver available?  True
isopened?  False
open?  False
Last Error  Driver not loaded Driver not loaded
Drivers  ['QSQLITE', 'QMYSQL', 'QMYSQL3', 'QODBC', 'QODBC3', 'QPSQL', 'QPSQL7']
Check open?  False
```

I just wanted to know if I am missing something obvious?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was that my script couldn't load the SQL driver using libmysql.dll.  When I ran the script through command line (rather than via PyCharm) an error stating:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
```

This error was in in the PyCharm output, however I assumed this was a previous error.

The drivers were available when running :

```
print('Drivers ', self.db.drivers())
```

And getting output:

```
Drivers  ['QSQLITE', 'QMYSQL', 'QMYSQL3', 'QODBC', 'QODBC3', 'QPSQL', 'QPSQL7']
```

The solution was to place the path to the libmysql.dll in Windows Environmental Variables